# Create a default Description Template in Perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

What are the steps and commands to create a default Description Template in Perforce on client side not server. For example, the description should look like this whenever user creates a new changelist.

Row1 :
Row2 :
Row3 :

Row4 :

I think we can use form-out. what are the steps and commands involved? There are no proper articles on net. If here we can get solution it will be really helpful.

Comment: You can use triggers to do this very easily, but that happens on the server (before the changelist form is sent to the client), and you said "client side, not server side".  If you specifically want to customize the changelist window in P4V, check out https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4vjs-ug/Content/P4VJS-UG/html-actions.html.

Comment: For the CLI, the equivalent would be to do something with `P4EDITOR` (e.g. a script that modifies the change description before invoking the regular editor).  My recommended approach would be to just do it from the server so it works with any client, though.  See https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2534 for an example.